# clearInterval doesn't work when ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

do you guys have any idea why can't this clear interval? i need this to be clean when ajax complete.

```
var startTimer = function(){
    setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

var stopTimer = function(){
    clearInterval(countdown);
}

var countdown = function(){
    console.log('listening');
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {

    if (settings.url.split('?')[1] == undefined)
        stopTimer();
    else
        startTimer();

});
```

Comment: You need to call `stopInterval()` on the reference returned by `setInterval()` *not* on the function you execute in the interval itself.

Comment: @Maximilly Moreira Gonçalves — If you want to post an answer, then post an answer. Don't fix the code in the question so the question asks about a problem that doesn't exist in it any more.